# Hall's paper on the profinite groups and Andre Weils "voisinage" notion

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, abstract-algebra, profinite-groups

I am reading through a classical paper [A Topology for Free Groups and Related Groups](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969513?seq=3)
by Marshall Hall Jr. in which profinite groups are defined for the first time.

There he defines on p. 129:

> *Definition*: Suppose the group $G$ contains a family $\Theta(V_i)$ of subgroups of $G$ such that:
>
> (1) $\bigcap_i V_i = 1$ all $V_i \in \Theta$
>
> (2) If $V,V' \in \Theta$ then $V\cap V' \in \Theta$
>
> (3) If $V \in \Theta$ then there is a normal subgroup $V' \in \Theta$ such that $V' \subseteq V$.
>
> If we take all sets $xV, Vx$, $V \in \Theta, x \in G$ as a basis for open sets in $G$, then $G$ becomes a topological group. We say that this is a subgroup topology for $G$ defined by the family $\Theta$.

At two points he makes references to Andre Weil and his "voisinage's" and on p. 131 in particular:

> Following A. Weil [10, page 10] a group $G$ with a subgroup topology defined by a family $\Theta(V_i)$ of subgroups is a uniform space. We suppose the subgroups $V_i$ indexed. Here for $x \in G$, $V_i(x)$ is the coset $V_ix$. Thus in the space $G\times G$ we define $V^i$ to be the set of pairs $(p,q)$ where $q \in V_i(p)$. In terms of this uniform structure [10, pp. 17-19] $G$ my be completed by a Cauchy sequence to a complete space $\hat{G}$.

This paragraph I cannot follow, first of all I do not have access to Weil's publication (and even if I would I can not read french). So are there any other resources where I can find more about the constructions done here, in particular what is meant by Cauchy sequence, I just know them for metric spaces?

Comment: I think the key expression here is "uniform structure", which makes notions like Cauchy sequence legitimate.   Concerning "voisinage", this occurs in the Bourbaki foundations of topology among other places, where a "neighborhood" of a point is just a set containing an open set containing the point.   Anyway, there is a translated Bourbaki chapter on uniform topologies relevant to groups and subgroup topologies, as well as other possible sources.   I recalled some of this language in section 16 of my Springer Lecture Notes 789 (1980) on arithmetic groups, for instance.